# Why the count is displayed in the category when the post under a category is deleted?

Tags: wordpress

In this category basics of money count is shown as 2, but actually there is only one post under this category basics of money. then why the count is shown as 2 in this table list?

[image]

Comment: That might be because the product is still in trash, trashed products still "take place" and are counted in this case, as they still exist in the DB

Comment: everything is deleted from the trash

Comment: You can also try clearing orphan variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in another post types there are some posts added under the category of basics of money. that's why it shows as 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to transients or we do some multiple process at a time or insert the products using CSV where we have by mistaken added wrong thing.

So, to overcome this I think you need to go to
WooCommerce --> Status --> Tools [Tab] --> Term counts [Click on Recount Terms]

Thanks